Why does dot product proof in Strang has a vector subtraction?
Question 1
Addition is showing v PLUS w , while proof is showing v MINUS w. I am intuitively not able to make out the minus part ?
Question 2
When you read Strang without previous linear algebra knowledge, it feels like proof is non-intuitive dense and without any hard proof ? Would like people to share experience.
Figure 1.8

Strang's style is very intuitive and conversational, and his book is perhaps not the best place to find tight, rigorous mathematics. (I myself wrote a linear algebra text, quite influenced by Strang, but with more attention to teaching students how to read and write proofs.) Note that the hypotenuse of the right triangle with legs $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ is the vector that goes from the head of $\vec w$ to the head of $\vec v$, so this is the equation $\vec w + (\vec v - \vec w) = \vec v$.

Draw a picture of $v$ with its tail at the origin and $w$ with its tail at the origin. Let’s assume $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal. Now draw the vector that goes from the head of $w$ to the head of $v$. That vector is $v - w$.

The proof refers to Figure 1.8, but you only showed us figure 1.1. Perhaps you should look at Figure 1.8 instead.

@TedShifrin I am honored to exchange mathy stuff with a math wizard like you. Thank you :-)

@DavidK new page posted. I just cannot get who decides a PLUS or a MINUS between two vectors. I cannot seem to "get" why order of traversal decides a + or - . Infact the proof will work if ${\left| v \right|}^2 + {\left| w \right|}^2 = {\left| v + w \right|}^2 $ too

If the two vectors $v$ and $w$ are perpendicular, then you can draw a rectangle with edges parallel to $v$ and $w$ and of the same lengths as $v$ and $w$, and both diagonals of a rectangle are the same. So it is true that you could do a correct proof with $v+w$ on the right instead of $v-w$. The $v-w$ construction, however, generalizes nicely to a proof of the Law of Cosines with the vectors are not perpendicular, however, while $v+w$ is (just slightly) more awkward to use in that case.

@DavidK who decides if the vector between $v$ and $w$ is  $ \left| v - w \right| $ or $ \left| v + w \right| $

$\left| v - w \right|$ is not a vector; it's a number. $v - w$ is a vector. As for "who decides," who decided that $+$ is addition and $-$ is subtraction? Someone long ago who popularized these symbols and got people to agree that that's what they meant. It's the same with definitions such as the addition and subtraction of vectors. Things are defined that way because people found them useful.

@DavidK Thank you for your reply. I will preface all my statements by saying that Strang's book (& others) "dump" ideas like vector between $v$ and $w$ is $v-w$ without addressing the "intuition" behind it. Another example is another question posted by me (question 4926962) . Strang does not "develop" the idea of "why minus" . It seems we have to "accept" it unless we read the entire text get an "ah-ha" moment , research internet etc. But again thanks for your replies. They are helpful and added to insight

There seem to be several layers of questions here:

What is the intuition of vector addition?
What is the intuition of vector subtraction?
How can you identify whether vectors are added or subtracted in a geometric figure?
Why did Strang write a proof in which vector $w$ is subtracted from vector $v$, not added?

So let's suppose we have two vectors $v$ and $w$, each of which we interpret geometrically as a distance and direction, as in this example:

Here are three different ways that we can "draw" the sum $v + w$ in for the same two vectors $v$ and $w$:

We typically accept the idea that two parallel arrows of the same length pointing in the same direction are identically the same vector, because the kind of vector we're dealing with here is completely identified by its length and direction;
it doesn't have a fixed starting point.
So we can draw the arrow for $w$ starting at the tip of the arrow for $v$,
or draw the two arrows starting at the same point and draw a parallelogram to find the tip of the vector $v + w$, or we can draw the arrow for $v$ starting at the tip of $w$.
It's always the same two vectors in these figures and the sum $v + w$ is always the same.
There are two ways to look at vector subtraction, just as there are two ways of looking at subtraction of numbers.
Let's talk about numbers instead of vectors for a moment.
Consider the subtraction $5 - 2 = 3.$ We could interpret this as
$5 + (-2) = 3,$ that is, subtraction is just like addition except that one of the numbers is "flipped" (has its sign changed);
or we could interpret it as saying that $2 + 3 = 5$, that is, a
subtraction is just a rearrangement of the terms in an addition.
Another way you might say this is that the number $5 - 2$ is the number you need to add to $2$ to get $5$ as the sum.
Strang seems to be taking the last approach with vectors. The vector $u - v$ is the vector you need to add to $v$ in order to get $u$ as the sum.
Now let $u = v + w$ in any of the diagrams above.
Then $w = u - v,$ just like arithmetic on numbers.
Assigning the name $u$ to the vector $v + w$ in this figure,

we get this:

Notice that the vector $u - v$ in this diagram starts at the tip of $v$ and ends at the tip of $u$. So that's always a legitimate way to represent $u - v$.
In general, if you have a figure with vectors labeled $u$, $v$, and $u - v$,
it had better be possible to add $u - v$ to $v$ and get $u$ as the result.
If not, the vectors are mislabeled.

How can you tell whether vectors are being added or subtracted?
If the diagram looks like one of the three $v + w$ diagrams,
or if you can make it look like one of them by redrawing one or more of the vectors starting at a different point, it's addition.
If it looks like the last diagram, or can be made to look like it by changing the starting point(s) of one or more vectors, it's subtraction.
Do enough of these exercises and you'll recognize which one it is more easily.
It's true that this definition of the operations $+$ and $-$ on vectors is somewhat arbitrary. After all, when we first introduce vectors, every operation on them is technically a new, never-before-seen operation and we are free to name those operations as we please. But in this case there is an intuitive reason to choose the operations the way we do.
The vectors in the examples above were plotted on a Cartesian coordinate system that I erased after plotting them; in the coordinate system, the coordinates of the vectors $v$ and $w$ were
$v = \begin{bmatrix} 3\\2 \end{bmatrix}$
and $w = \begin{bmatrix} 5\\-1 \end{bmatrix}.$
According to the conventional definitions of linear algebra, then,
$$
 v + w
 = \begin{bmatrix} 3\\2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 5\\-1 \end{bmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 + 5\\2 + (-1) \end{bmatrix} 
 = \begin{bmatrix} 8\\1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
That is, "addition" of vectors can be accomplished by adding the coordinates of the vectors. If we were to swap the definitions of $+$ and $-$ in the expressions $v+w$ and $v-w,$ we would compute $v+w$ by subtracting coordinates and $v-w$ by adding coordinates. I think that would be confusing.
Also note that in the example above, the second example of plotting $v + w$ plots it as one of the diagonals of a parallelogram.
You can plot $v - w$ on the same figure by connecting the tips of $v$ and $w$, that is, $v - w$ is the other diagonal of the same parallelogram.
In most cases, the diagonals of a parallelogram are aligned in different directions and have different lengths.
The one case in which
$\lVert v + w \rVert$ and $\lVert v - w \rVert$
are equal is when $v$ and $w$ are perpendicular,
which just happens to be the case we are interested in in this particular theorem in Strang's book.
It also comes about via the conventional definitions that
$v + w = w + v$ but $v - w = -(w - v),$ that is, the $+$ operation on vectors is commutative, just like the $+$ operation on numbers, but $v - w$ points in the exact opposite direction from $w - v,$ just as $5 - 2$ is the exact "opposite" of $2 - 5$ (one is $3$ while the other is $-3$).

As for why Strang subtracts $w$ from $v$ instead of adding the two vectors: because he can, and because this leads to a proof that is correct.
As it happens, you could alternatively make another equally correct proof that used the vector sum $v + w$ instead of the difference $v - w$.
Strang simply chose to do it with $v - w$, perhaps because if you have already drawn vectors $v$ and $w$ on a diagram the way they are drawn in the very first diagram in this answer -- both vectors "starting" at the same point -- then the easy and direct way to turn the diagram into a triangle is to connect the tips of $v$ and $w$ with a difference of the two vectors, either $v - w$ or $w - v$.
More generally, when you look at a proof, the kind of question you should ask is not, "Why must the proof be written this way?" Usually that question is based on a false premise; a different proof is possible.
Rather, you should ask, "How does the proof work when it is written this way?"
With regard to this proof, don't ask why $w$ had to subtracted from $v$.
Ask what we're able to do with the vector difference after we have subtracted $w$ from $v$.

Cannot appreciate the extensive answer ! However, if you can imagine $$v$$ and $$w$$ as two sticks held at an angle in one palm of your hand. Somehow, arbitrarily decided vector in between is a $$+$$ or a $$-$$. Overtime, it became convention. You replacing $$v+w$$ with $$u$$ does the trick but I am arguing from natural law standpoint. I am assuming no major theorem would change in linear algebra if the convention was revered.

What is "natural law" in mathematics? All symbols are in some sense arbitrarily given meanings, and the same symbol technically has different meanings in different contexts, but we like the meanings to be analogous. I think you would find linear algebra much more difficult to learn if the conventions of vector $+$ and $-$ were reversed. See the examples added to the answer.

@NewStudent "I am assuming no major theorem would change in linear algebra if the convention was reversed." Vector addition is commutative, but vector subtraction is not. That is, $u+v=v+u$, but $u-v=-(v-u)$. So it is not mere convention - there are big differences between these operations.
